# Modifying an array through a reference

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a subroutine that will receive an array reference and then delete some of the elements of the array. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 6);
func1 (\@a);

sub func1 {
    my $a = shift;

    my @b = (2, 6);

    for my $val_to_remove (@b) {
        for my $i (0..$#$a) {
            my $val = $a->[$i];
            if ( $val == $val_to_remove ) {
                splice @$a, $i, 1;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This seems, to say the least, a little awkward using two `for` loops. 
Is it possible to simplify this?

I also tried

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 6);

my $temp = \@a;
func2 (\$temp );

sub func2 {
    my $a = shift;

    $$a = [2, 6];
}
```

but then `@a` is not modified, but rather `$temp` will be..

I would also rather like to avoid passing a reference to a reference, since that will mess up the calling syntax for other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hash as an indicator function for identifying efficiently the items to be removed; use a grep for filtering them out:

```
sub func1 {
    my $a = shift;
    my %b = map { ($_ => 1) } (2, 6);
    @$a = grep { !$b{$_} } @$a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Loic's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29879857/176646) works well and is quite readable. I would recommend it unless you're working with large arrays that cause the `grep` to eat a lot of memory, or if performance is absolutely critical.

You can get a bit of a performance boost by using `splice`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @haystack = (1, 2, 3, 6);

my %needle = map { $_ => 1 } (2, 6);

foreach my $i (reverse 0 .. $#haystack) {
    splice @haystack, $i, 1 if exists $needle{ $haystack[$i] };
}

dd \@haystack;
```

#### Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Note that you *must* iterate through `@haystack` in reverse order, since every time you remove an element, the remaining elements shift to the left, changing the array indexes.

### Benchmark

Here are the results from a slightly modified version of BrowserUk's [corrected benchmark](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1036756;spoil=1), written in response to [foreach array - delete current row ?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1036622;spoil=1) on PerlMonks. The original benchmark included several other methods for removing elements from an array, which I've left out for simplicity.

```
$ ./benchmark -N=1e2
              Rate       grep for_splice
grep       40959/s         --       -37%
for_splice 65164/s        59%         --
$ ./benchmark -N=1e3
             Rate       grep for_splice
grep       4072/s         --       -38%
for_splice 6515/s        60%         --
$ ./benchmark -N=1e4
            Rate       grep for_splice
grep       366/s         --       -33%
for_splice 550/s        50%         --
$ ./benchmark -N=1e5
             Rate       grep for_splice
grep       32.7/s         --       -38%
for_splice 52.9/s        62%         --
$ ./benchmark -N=1e6
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)

             Rate       grep for_splice
grep       2.36/s         --       -28%
for_splice 3.28/s        39%         --
```

And the benchmark code itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -sl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark 'cmpthese';

our $N //= 1e3;
our $I //= -1;

# 10% the size of the haystack
my $num_needles = int($N / 10) || 1;

our @as;
@{ $as[ $_ ] } = 1 .. $N for 0 .. 4;

our %needle = map { int(rand($N)) => 1 } 1 .. $num_needles;

cmpthese $I, {
    for_splice => q[
        my $ar = $as[0];
        foreach my $i (reverse 0 .. $#$ar) {
            splice @$ar, $i, 1 if exists $needle{ $ar->[$i] };
        }
        $I == 1 and print "0: ", "@$ar";
    ],
    grep => q[
        my $ar = $as[1];
        @$ar = grep { ! exists $needle{$_} } @$ar;
        $I == 1 and print "1: ", "@$ar";
    ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and the link to PerlMonks. That was very instructive!

Comment: @HåkonHægland Glad it was useful. Unfortunately, I realized after posting this that the benchmark [is flawed](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1124823). BrowserUk posted an updated benchmark that shows `splice` having an edge for smaller arrays (up to ~10,000 elements), but after that it lags significantly. The other three approaches, which I omitted from this answer, are consistently faster than both `grep` and `splice`, for both large and small arrays. I'll update my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a simple `for (LIST)` loop to iterate over the indices of an array if you're also modifying the contents of the array. That's because the index of the last item may change, and you will also skip over elements if you delete the current element *and* increment the counter.

A `while` loop is required instead, or the equivalent C-style `for`.

This program demonstrates, as well as uing `List::Util::any` to check whether an array elemnent should be deleted

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'any';

my @a = (1, 2, 3, 6);
func1 (\@a);

use Data::Dump;
dd \@a;

sub func1 {
    my ($a) = @_;
    my @b = (2, 6);

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < @$a; ) {
      if ( any { $a->[$i] == $_ } @b ) {
        splice @$a, $i, 1;
      }
      else {
        ++$i;
      }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! Great to know how to use a C-style for loop. This was just what I was trying to achieve.. I am always learning something new from you.. :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Are you familiar with C? I've left out the third clause of the `for`, which would normally be `++$i` because the index is incremented only when there is no match. As it stands, it's identical to `my $i = 0;` `while ( $i < @$a ) { ... }` which you may prefer

Answer (score 0):

With problems of this nature, it is often easier to build the array you want rather than delete from an existing one.

```
my @a = ( 1, 2, 3, 6 );

sub func1 {
  my $aref = shift @_;
  my @b = ( 2, 6 );

  my @results = ();
  for my $item ( @$aref ){
    if( grep { $item == $_ } @b ){
      next;
    }
    push @results, $item;
  }
  return @results;
}

my @results = func1( \@a );
say "@results";
```

Comment: If you want to create a new array, you can also use `array_minus` from [`Array::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Utils#array_minus) or `get_unique` from [`List::Compare`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare).